# Port forwarding from one router to router, then to a machine on the second router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a combo modem/router provided by my ISP. I plugged a second router into this device because the wireless speeds were subpar. Now I am trying to set up a home media server that is accessible from outside the network using a dynamic DNS service. I have the dynamic DNS working correctly, but now I am trying to tunnel the data from the internet-facing router at 192.168.0.1 to the second router at 192.168.1.1

I am probably going down the wrong road here, but I set the second router to have an IP of 192.168.0.150, so as to put it on the same subnet as the other router. I then forwarded the ports I need to that location, where I then have that router forwarding those same ports to the correct machine. None of this works, and I can no longer connect to the internet from machines on that second router. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: double NAT could be avoided by either A)putting the internet facing device  in bridge mode or B)putting the second device into AP mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first router is being used as a router, and the second router is being used as a Wireless Access Point (AP) - it doesn't need to be a router, as it resides on the same network as the first router.

Connect the AP router to the first router via LAN ports.  Turn off DHCP on the AP router.

Now all the LAN ports both routers, and the wifi network on the AP router are all on the same subnet because they are bridged.  They can all use DHCP from the first router.  Because in this configuration, you are connecting them as a layer two network, which means that broadcast traffic, such as DHCP requests, can be seen by every device.

Effectively, you can ignore the port forwarding on the second router, and port forward on the first router directly to devices connected to the second routers wireless network.