# What is the right way to connect to a modem to a router, connected to another router?

Tags: router

I'd like to have a setup like this:

```
Modem -> new router -> old router -> computer
           |
          \./
        computer
```

So far what I've done is:

1. turn everything off for like 60 seconds (I believe this is especially important for 'powercycling' the modem to reset which router its talking to)
2. turn on the modem (then wait 60 seconds)
3. connect the modem to the new router's WAN port, and turn on the new router
4. connect to the old router (via wifi) and access its admin portal, and:

   - turn off NAT and its DHCP server
   - give it an IP address different from the new router
5. connect one of the new router's LAN ports to the old router's WAN port
6. connect to the old router via wifi

I was having trouble getting the new router to properly interface with the modem before power cycling the modem. But after I made sure to power cycle the modem, at least the new router seems to be able to talk to the modem. After I followed the above steps:

- I can connect via wifi to the new router and internet works
- I can connect via wifi to the old router, but internet does not work
- I can see in the status of old router that its default gateway is the new router, as it should be

I have read in various places that you might need to connect a LAN port from the new router to a LAN port from the old router, but when I do this, the status in the old router says in red letters "The WAN port is disconnected" and it does not have a default gateway when I tried that.

What do I need to do to get the old router to be able to serve internet via its connection to the new router?

Comment: Thanks for including that connectivity diagram -- it's hugely helpful.

Comment: What is your goal here?  What is the purpose for having two separate networks?  Typically, this question is asked because people want to use a separate wifi access point to the one in their main router - is this the case here?

Comment: The purpose is plugs in different rooms. What I left out is the powerline adapters I just bought. I want the good router ("old router") in my room for nice ac wifi (which seems to have terrible range), and in my roommate's room, he can plug directly into the other router ("new router").

Comment: In that case, the LAN to LAN approach is correct - it is essentially the same as this question: http://superuser.com/questions/893116/port-forwarding-from-one-router-to-router-then-to-a-machine-on-the-second-route/893120#893120

Comment: @Paul So I did see that question before I posted this. I turned dhcp off on the old router, and connected the routers LAN to LAN, but I still didn't get internet when connecting to the old router via wifi. The router also complained about its WAN being disconnected, as i mentioned in the question. Is there something else i'd need to do?

Comment: Tried it again and its working! I have no idea what i did differently the first time. Thanks paul!

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind:

1. Ensure that the old router's subnet is different from that of the new router.  For example, 192.168.1.xxx for the old router, and 192.168.2.xxx for the new router.
2. In addition to defining the old router's gateway as the new router's IP, try adding the IP of the new router as a DNS server for the old router. Also make sure that at least one of the DNS servers that shows up on the new router's IP autoconfiguration is present as a DNS server for the old router; you may have to add this manually.

Comment: So the ip address of the old router is 192.168.0.1, and the new router is 192.168.1.1. Is that sufficient for your point #1? I also set the new router's primary DNS server to 192.168.1.1, that didn't seem to help

Comment: Yep, those subnets are fine for #1. For #2, as long as you didn't make a typo in your comment, you set the DNS server on the wrong router.  'Old router' should have a DNS server set to 192.168.1.1.  Also, per my edit just now, I left out that 'old router' probably also needs at least one external DNS server -- copy over as many from the DHCP autoconfig of the 'new router' as will fit in the manual config for 'old router.'

Comment: Oh yeah, i reversed my comment - i mean i set the old router's primary DNS server to 192.168.1.1. In any case, i got it working without the DNS stuff

Comment: <tips hat> Happy to try. Advanced networking is definitely not at the top of my skill set.